# Fixing PHP Notices and Warnings?

Tags: php

I'm getting notices and warnings for this BMR Calculator PHP script, but I'm not sure whats causing them at all since these messages are only showing up in Firefox. [Heres a screenshot](http://d.pr/6kUq)

I added the php/html directly to my template file and turned php on for that file is that correct? [Here is the php/html](http://d.pr/Lrt2)

Comment: This is based on assumption from your provided image. You have 2 variables that are either undefined or used before being defined. The divide by zero happens because, well, you divided by zero. Maybe using a php `ini_set('display_errors', false);` will solve the problem (just a hunch).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with:

```
$gender    = $_REQUEST['gender'];
$met       = $_REQUEST['metric'];
```

They're not defined in the query string or the posted data.

You could resolve the issue with an isset check.

```
# If gender is not set, set it to male by default.
$gender = isset( $_REQUEST['gender'] ) ? $_REQUEST['gender'] : 'male';
```

Comment: `empty()` is a better check than `isset()`, because if the variable is set, but empty (`#_POST['gender'] = ''`), you'll still want to default to `male`.

Comment: I usually avoid empty in checks of REQUEST vars, since a value of 0 returns TRUE on an empty() check -- also, I believe an empty check of an undefined variable will give a warning?

Comment: You may be right on point #1 (never experienced this specifically), but your 2nd point is incorrect. `empty()` is shorthand for `! isset($var) || ( isset($var) && $var == FALSE )`. From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): "A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist."